# help with javascript and text area

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html

Hey my text from textarea is not showing in my div area within my contentplaceholder.

Could any one advice whats going wrong with my javascript?

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" Runat="Server">
<link href="css/Style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder2" Runat="Server">
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.5.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('button').click(function () {
        var x = $('textarea').val();
        $('div').html(x);
    });
</script>

<textarea style="border: 0" cols="77" rows="5"></textarea>
<button>Post Message</button>

<div></div>
</asp:Content>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The button isn't in the DOM yet when your script runs.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
      $('button').click(function () {
        var x = $('textarea').val();
        $('div').html(x);
      });
    });
</script>
```

That'll tell jQuery to hold on to that initialization function until the DOM is ready.  When that's the case, your function will be called.

Optionally, you could move your script block to the end of the `<body>`, but that'd be somewhat *déclassé*.

The story is that scripts are run as soon as the browser has seen the whole `<script>` element.  When you put the script at the top like that, there aren't any `<button>` elements yet because the browser hasn't made it that far through the document.

Comment: ahh damm it worked thanks but for some reason it made the screen blank with the style there and the text duplicated rather than post the text in the div container inside the content placer holder??? Sorry for the confusion but i have a master page with the style set, then my content page with the script above but when i try post it makes a blank page with the grey background from my style sheet with the text i wrote in the textarea (duplicated aswell) what on earth is going on?

Comment: seems rather than add text into my div its changing the master page divs all at once? is this correctable with div id? if so how could I change the java for a div id if that will even work?

Comment: Yes - that statement, `$('div').html(x);` says to change the contents of **every** `<div>` on your page :-)  You can give one an "id" value and then use `$('#theSpecialDiv').html(x);`.

Comment: thanks man all works fine i was missing the # when i tryed the id :( sadness. there is another problem tho asp seems to be set for autopost back so when i hit the html button it adds the text but then the page reloads and the data is lost. Any idea how to correct that?

Comment: Oh; sorry I didn't notice that before. Try adding `return false;` to the end of that "click" handler function. That will tell jQuery to prevent the default action of the button from happening; the default action is (probably) to submit a form :-)

Comment: and once again Briliant! Java is so cool! Thanks for the help!  Now I need to expand on it, how would I get it to add a div each time? Rather than overwrite the div text in the current code atm

Comment: You may want to open a new question about that part. It'll give other people a chance to offer answers and insight.

Comment: javaSCRIPT, Garrith... Java is indeed very cool, but is not related to javascript in any way whatsoever (other than having a similar sounding name).

Answer (score 2):

To elaborate on Pointy's answer, move your script beneath the

```
</div>
```

or wrap your code in an init() function that you call from the body tag via an onload as in...

```
<script>
    function whateverIwantToHappenWhenTheDomLoads(){
     //put your code here

}

</script>

<body onload="whateverIwantToHappenWhenTheDomLoads()">

...
```